# How do I fix the drain in our refrigerator

Tags: leak, refrigerator

It's a GE TBX25PASJRAA.  Water collects in the refrigerator compartment, a tray placed at the back of the top shelf catches most of it.

I assume it's defrost water that's not going where it's supposed to.  I had originally thought the drain line was plugged but when I pulled the fridge out I see it contains a trap with water in it which strongly implies it's not blocked.  This is part #315 on this diagram:

[Parts Diagram](http://www.partselect.com/ModelFrames.aspx?ModelID=431731&ModelNum=TBX25PASJRAA&mfgModelNum=&ManufactureID=2&Selected=00109594i05&Position=1&mfg=GE&Type=&Mark=2)

Also, I'm not finding any manuals that indicate how to work on it.  Do such things exist anymore?

Comment: Have you tried entering the part number "TBX25PASJRAA" into the search box found here: http://www.geappliances.com/service_and_support/literature/

Comment: @Mike Perry: I've already been there--it produces an owner's manual, not a repair manual.

Comment: where is the drain located## Heading ## for a self defrosting whirlpool refrigerator

Comment: @robertwhisler:  There's a rigid tube coming down the middle of the back of the unit.  I believe it's supposed to deliver the water down by the compressor to be evaporated.

Answer (score 1):

just because the water i making it to the tray outside the fridge doesn't mean the drain isn't clogged. it might be partially obstructed and it can't drain fast enough.

also, i would check the entire drain assembly end to end. it might be that the parts are not fitted tightly and are therefore leaking.

Comment: What I was saying is that water in the trap means water is getting there (it didn't dry out) and since the rest of it isn't full it can't be plugged.  I think there must be a leak somewhere before it gets to the drain.